# updating a particular field with id in php my sql data table

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

[image: Scrrenshot Of Page]

Above is the screen shot of my page. My problem is i'm getting the data from my sql table and creating a php data table like this:

```
<?php
$s="select * from events join event_time on (events.event_id=event_time.event_id)

where events.isapproved='N' ";
$res=mysql_query($s);
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='2' >
<tr>
<th>title</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>link</th>
<th>start_date</th>
<th>start_time</th>
<th>end_date</th>
<th>isapproved</th> 
</tr>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $res )) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo " <td>".$info['title'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['email'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['address'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['link'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['start_date'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['start_time'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['end_date'] . "</td> ";
echo "<td><a href=yes.php?".$info['event_id'] .">".$info['isapproved'] ."</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href=del.php?".$info['event_id'].">".'Delete'."</a></td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

The hyper link what i am trying to acces is
yes.php

```
<?php
include("config/config.php");

$sq="select * from events";
$res=mysql_query($sq);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
if($row['isapproved']=='N')
{
$id=$row['event_id'];

}
}
$sql="UPDATE events SET isapproved= 'Y'
WHERE event_id='$id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


header("Location:admin.php");
?>
```

See, The function is when i click that hyper link "N" my table has to be updated(as you can see in the query) with value "Y".

The real problem is i am getting the id when i click on "N" but when the query gt updated the row at the bottom of the table is updating as "Y". What is the problem? Can anyone look into it.. I'm dying looking out of it...

Comment: Can you do a var_dump and show us a few rows in rendered HTML, so we can see what values are for N and Y?

Comment: Do you really want all of your existing row has been updated with a single click of any row??? Or want to update only one rows which was clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you want the following thing. At first change your php data table with this :

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $res )) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo " <td>".$info['title'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['email'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['address'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['link'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['start_date'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['start_time'] . "</td> ";
echo " <td>".$info['end_date'] . "</td> ";
echo "<td><a href=yes.php?id=".$info['event_id'] .">".$info['isapproved'] ."</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href=del.php?".$info['event_id'].">".'Delete'."</a></td></tr>";

}
```

Then change the `yes.php` file with the following code:

```
<?php
include("config/config.php");
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="UPDATE events SET isapproved= 'Y'
WHERE event_id='$id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


header("Location:admin.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
$sq="select * from events";
$res=mysql_query($sq);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
if($row['isapproved']=='N')
{
$id=$row['event_id'];

}
}
```

You are grabbing the id of all unapproved events and storing them (overwriting) in `$id`. You probably want to change all of that to `$id = intval($_GET['id']);`, and in your other page change `<a href=yes.php?".$info['event_id'] .">` to `<a href=yes.php?id=".$info['event_id'] .">`.

You may also want to add your own validation on that input. Keep in mind that anything sent through get is insecure. If someone sends in an attempt at an injection attack `intval` will just convert it to an integer (`0` if it fails to convert), so you're safe from that but people could fake any id they wanted and have it's status changed. Also if you have an event with id `0` a failed intval will modify it instead of nothing if you don't test for that.